# What motivating factors does Stack Overflow offer new users?

Tags: discussion

This question is not meant to reflect any experiences good or bad that I have had on this or any other Stack Exchange site.

Many people who are members of SO have been here for a long. Most of them likely don't remember if they felt unwelcome when they joined and if they did, they have put it behind them and moved on. Much like the tides, there are always people coming and going. Just like the constant changing of the tides changes the shoreline, the constant changing of the community members changes the atmosphere of the Stack Overflow Communities. Often this happens so gradual that nobody even notices. I have not been a member of Stack Overflow from the beginning or even close to the beginning therefore I am not qualified to positively judge exactly what the atmosphere was like.

A 2013 study has found that 75% of users only ask one question and 65% only answer one question. I don't have to explain how numbers like that would affect Walmart or any other business.

Stack Overflow has over 4,000,000 registered users. It is my bet, most have very limited programming knowledge. If you have ever tried to learn to play a musical instrument and had some say "Just do this,it's easy". It is not easy if you have never done it. Programming and coding is the same way, it is not easy if you have not done much of it. Why do people with limited abilities end up asking their questions that don't meet the standards of the Stack Overflow Community. Because Google sends them to Stack Overflow. There is no better place to get answers for their coding question than here. (Motivating factor #1)

So when I see condescending comments accusing people of not doing enough work, asking a low quality questions or that refer to someone else's work "crap" or "garbage". My favourite example is "polishing a turd" it is easy to see why 75% of users only ask one question. It is not important who made the comments or when they were made. What is important, it doesn't continue. It is also easy to see why the people who care about this site would like to see some changes. Hats off to Jay Hanlon. If a new users contribution is met with hostility, most are not going to just endure and hope it gets better. They are going to leave or limit their participation. Not every new user's work is called "crap/garbage" but often are not treated the best. It is not their fault that they end up on Stack Overflow and it is not their fault they don't know the rules. 750,000 people out of 1,000,000 never ask another question and it costs nothing to show a little compassion and understanding.

If a new user feels he/she is met with hostility or feels unwelcome, what motivating factors does Stack Overflow offer that would make it worth staying?

### Update

When I wrote this question I was expecting people to point out all the good things Stack Overflow has to offer. I was hopefully that these answer may motivate some people to look past the perceived hostility and give the community a chance to prove that this is not the case. I was completely blown away when I found comments that were encouraging people to leave.

Comment: (1) "There are people with high reputation points that feel it is either their right or their responsibility to point out the flaws and short coming of the less experienced users" -- "Right" and "responsibility" might be too strong words, but there is no way to do content curation here without pointing out flaws in posts (and note I say "posts", not "users"). (2) "I have read numerous comments calling other people's work crap of garbage." -- That, on the other hand, can and should be avoided. It is not a necessary part of curation, as opposed to identifying flaws in posts and acting upon them.

Comment: If you mean askers - what motivation they need except getting answer to their question?

Comment: My comments are a little tangential, in that they just attempt to clarify the framing of the question. The second one is perhaps too tangential, so I'm going to delete it.

Comment: Well, I have certainly used 'Trash code' as a phrase, on C 'i++ + ++i' posts.  Note 'trash code' not 'trash user', and none of the code in such posts is the OP's original work - it's all copypasta homework/quiz questions, it's in the FAQ, it's been duplicated 100's of times, it stll appears a couple imtes a week.  Despite that, I still got punished for using that phrase.  So, if other users are posting 'garbage' 'crap' comments on a regualr basis, I have to ask, why are they not suspended?

Comment: 'I excluded the examples from the question to avoid pointing a finger at anyone' no.  You slag posters/comments off, you should provide evidence!  Post the links!

Comment: This is meta - moderation is deliberately lax here because you need some rep to post - it's not freely public, and mods etc. need to know about the issues raised here, so you won't get hit for posting links to bad posts. We've had similar 'anti-user-moderator' posts before, and I have always asked for evidence/links, so, please, post/edit away:)

Comment: [*crap and garbage*](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/845687) but loads of false positives.

Comment: Whether they get answer or not is not quite relevant to the question. You ask what motivation they have to ask. And motivation is simple - they need answer.

Comment: Motivation besides finding solutions to their programming headaches? Not sure... Learning to search is one of the most valuable skills a programmer should have.

Comment: @rene sure, but good of you to do a quick query anyway.  I only looked at the first 10, and none of them fall into the category of comments about which the user is complaining, they're all 'garbage in the buffer, crap data, garbage pointer' and all that 'normal' code/test/debug stuff.

Comment: The only easy way to see evidence of this issue is if the OP posts their examples, something that has not happened yet...............

Comment: The main issue I see @Martin is that new users see moderation as aggressive. When we ask for examples,  we are given "my question was closed, or a dupe I dont understand was chosen, or it got downvoted, or the comments explaining how to fix it sounded condescending". These are all things older users are used to and see differently. There is a big discrepancy in our PoVs comparing to new users.... which PoV is right is debatable.... but it does seem to be the basis of the friction.  It's also why examples provided don't always ring 'true' to the other side imho

Comment: @Patrice IKR, but what are those users going to do when they are'downvote' and 'closevoted' by their compilers/linkers issuing error-messages?  What are they going to do when they are faced with continual test/debug loops when their software does something, but not what they want?  The tools and processors just don't care about frustration and feelings.  The users can moan and complain all they want, the bugs don't care.  That is the reality of software development and, if they cannot cope with some imaginary points loss on a website...

Comment: @Martin oh I agree with you there and I don't shy from my position. I just feel something could maybe be done for better expectation setting. Because actual user experience = service received - expectations. I think Stack did a terrible job at setting expectations. People are used to 'I Google my question, get to Stack, find my answer', without realizing the work done to get the answer posted. Over time they skip the Google step and come in with that expectation. No wonder they get disappointed

Comment: @Patrice sometimes, I sometimes think that new users should be given an 'Industry Health Warning' when signing up, maybe: 'NOTE WELL: developing software is really hard work.  Don't believe what you see in Hollywood.  It's often a ditch-digging exercise with testing and debugging, and 'writing code' is often a trivial exercise compared with getting the data right and testing/debugging.  You have been warned...'

Comment: I balme Hollywood for a lot.  It gives the impression that good software is somehow just a product of some nerdy, geeky genius, and that valued. highly-paid skilled/experienced software developers are just born that way, whereas I'm absolutely convinced that they got their most valuable skills by picking up a shovel and starting to dig.

Comment: @MartinJames I actually blame general social media (read: FB/insta and the like) where there is no mechanism of dissent/criticism. If only there was a dislike button there people wont think it as hostile

Comment: @LucianoFCastelfranchi: "*Their reward is an opportunity to earn more responsibility as a moderator or other high ranking position.*" I stopped getting "more responsibility" *years* ago (25K rep is the last time you get new privileges). Why am I still here? Oh right, because I enjoy providing knowledge; I enjoy solving interesting problems. That's why I came here in the first place, and that's why I'm still here. High rep answerers generally aren't doing it for fake internet points.

Comment: @Luciano: "*This attitude also leads to lower participation and reduced numbers of active users.*" I disagree. Yes, some people won't participate, but people who *don't* feel SO is hostile will participate. The latter group is not exactly small, and it isn't a shrinking number either. "*I believe the goal of Jay Hanlon blog-post is to alleviate tension between the newbie's and seasoned members.*" If that was the goal, it failed ***massively***. Especially with conflating issues regarding protected classes with issues regarding hostility in general.

Comment: @LucianoFCastelfranchi: Why would you want people to stay on a site they feel is hostile? That makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: @LucianoFCastelfranchi: You didn't ask about why "people" should stay. You asked about why "people that do find it hostile" should stay. You shouldn't pretend those are the same question.

Comment: @LucianoFCastelfranchi I'm not suggesting they be encouraged to leave, I'm suggesting it's their own best option.  If you go into a bar, it's serving good beer, and packed out, but you don't like the other customers or staff, just find another bar with good beer and customers etc. you can get on with.  There's no point in staying in a place where you feel unwelcome.  You just walk out the door - no bouncer has thrown you out.  You could always try the place again later, if you want to.

Comment: ..and the Quora and Reddit bars might have landlords, staff and customers that you get on with and so you don't feel such hostility.  They have bad beer, but at least you won't feel dissed.

Comment: @LucianoFCastelfranchi 'You having over 250,000 rep points....' I thought it was about feelings and perceptions, not numbers?

Comment: OK, a day later, and still no examples/links..........

Comment: That blog post is misteaching so many people what this site is about, what happens on it, and what downvotes mean. It's actively harmful, counter-productive to solving the very problem it purports to be trying to solve. I'm absolutely sure that it wasn't meant that way, but boy...

Answer (score 17):

OK, right, again:

> I have read the blog post Stack Overflow Isn’t Very Welcoming. It’s
>   Time for That to Change by Jay Hanlon.

That would be the one that purports that some invisible, undetectable, unprovable, racist/sexist bias-force has infested SO and needs an exorcism?  That the one?

> There are people with high reputation points that feel it is either
>   their right or their responsibility to point out the flaws and short
>   coming of the less experienced users

I suspect that in most cases user-moderators don't personally know the users, and so 'point out the flaws and shortcoming of the less experienced users' is too broad a brush and so inaccurate.  It's the code etc. that they posted that has flaws and shortcomings and the OP posted, in part, to find out what those issues are.

> right or their responsibility

'right' well, they are SO users with enough rep to vote/comment, so it's not forbidden. 'responsibility' they are volunteers with no responsibility to do anything. Nothing is contracted, no favour or barter is owed and there is no financial consideration.

> I have read numerous comments calling other people's work crap of
>   garbage.

Fine.  Links please... still waiting after an hour.  That's not long, and so I intend to wait for 24 hours before asking again for links.  rene has kindly knocked together a quick query for 'garbage', 'crap' strings but, naturally, they catch a lot of 'normal' software stuff - 'garbage collection', 'crap left in buffer' and the like.

Please post links to the ' numerous comments'.

> To earn a high reputation requires a lot of effort. Many of these
>   people spend possible an hour or more everyday on Stack Overflow.
>   Their reward is an opportunity to earn more responsibility as a
>   moderator or other high ranking position.

That's part of it for some.  I have no intention of ever becoming an actual diamond moderator - it's bad enough being a user-moderator.  If I have free time, it's good to spend some of it using my skills and experience to help others out of some hole.  That means putting down a ladder so they can climb out, not getting the ladder, climbing down, picking up the user and carrying them back up the ladder.

> ```
> When a new users contribution is met with hostility
> ```

....still waiting for those links.  You will have to further refine 'hostility' since some 'feel' that downvoting and closing bad questions, (that's 'bad questions' not 'newbie questions), is hostile,

> most are not going to just endure and hope it gets better.

If they ask good questions, they won't have to 'endure' any perceived 'hostility'.

> They are going to leave or limit their participation.

If they continually post bad questions, SO will limit their participation for them.

> If a new user feels he/she is met with hostility, what motivating
>   factors does Stack Overflow offer that would make it worth staying?

Probably none.  If they cannot cope with the 'hostility' of down and close votes, they will surely be unable to cope with software tools like compilers and interpreters that seen to continually seem to generate pages of hostile error messages, never mind the grind of continual test/debug phases as required to get bugs out  Such users should choose a different hobby/course/profession now, rather than wait until they meet an uncooperative, unhelpful, hostile, compiler/linker/make/test/debug.

If the 'hostility' extends to something flaggable, then flag it, but 'feelings' of hostility after down/close votes on a bad question won't cut it.

Comment: In addition, most problems with questions not even result from lack of programming skills, but - by my observation - more general skills, like asking a proper question, stating a problem clearly or even simply seraching the internet, i.e. using a search engine. Often a simple search with the title or other keywords in the text gives helpful results - among the first matches stack overflow. I'm not sure it is a matter of the quality of schools/universities or an increase of a "speeon-feed me" mentality, but a lot of askers have the attitude they deserve to be carried to the goal.

Comment: @LucianoFCastelfranchi: Respect and rudeness are two sides of a medal. New posters behaving as if they have a right to get an answer to however off-topic, malformed, unclear or complex their question is, having every information to solve their problem puilled out of their nose in the comments, Asking tons of follow-up questions in comments to an answer or their question, but complain/flag as rude when being told they need to read (how insulting!) the documentation, learn the language _basics_, etc. cost time for those who try to help. Killing someone's time is imo the worst insult.

Comment: And - as I wrote above - that's not even related to programming. So, yes, I very well support Martin. Knitting or cooking are also fine professions/hobbies.

Comment: @LucianoFCastelfranchi I beg to differ.  I went through your post point-by-point and explained why I agreed/disagreed with each section.  This last bit: 'f a new user feels he/she is met with hostility, what motivating factors does Stack Overflow offer that would make it worth staying?' is a conditional, and I concluded that, IF the user feels that SO is hostile, THEN they have probably no reason to stay.

Comment: @LucianoFCastelfranchi no, that is not what I posted.  You ae trying very hard to put me on the side of some line where the 'I'm an arrogant, uncaring user who hates newbies and wants them to just go away and never return' live.  Sorry, no.

Comment: @MartinJames: Here's the thing. Finding links for this stuff is difficult because, well, people generally don't collect links to terrible comments. It takes a certain mindset to see something unpleasant and decide to squirrel it away. Also, terrible comments do tend to be removed from the site once properly flagged; that is after all what you're supposed to do. However, if you want links to abusive behavior, just search online. There are plenty of twitter and Reddit posts about bad encounters with comments on SO from lower-rep users.

Comment: @Nicol a lot of these are 'my question got closed instead of answered' though. I am not saying Stack couldn't be better, or that the community should change its tone at times. I just feel like a lot of new users who find Stack tough don't see 'rude' the same way as we consider 'rude'. A lot of the complaints is basically 'if I get anything else than an answer to my problem I can c&p in my codebase, it's hostile'. It's.... Not a fun exercise to go hunt down rudeness amidst that sometimes.

Comment: 'overwhelming consciences from the comments...' no, that is an incorrect conclusion.   Choosing to leave a bar because you don't like the staff and customers is one thing, leaving because the landlord has barred you and the bouincer has thown you out is another.

Answer (score 2):

### General

I am broadly in support of Jay's blog post, though we'll have to wait and see what concrete proposals come out of it. I think the ethic of it is correct: some people have been excluded, and we all need to do better to improve that. Broadly, the worry is that the culture, language, unwritten rules, and codes of the site are especially intimidating for folks who (a) are beginners, or (b) are already experiencing exclusion in technology circles because of their gender, race or other protected category.

It sounds like your primary worry is about folks who seem to be hostile, and that they should [Be Nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) a bit more. I do think this is a problem, but it's hard to measure objectively, since speakers can seem to be more hostile than they actually meant to be, and one reader can be more susceptible to hostility than another person.

Some of your cited examples are OK if we're talking in generalities - no-one will gasp if you mention that there is a lot of "garbage" on the main site. However, if you comment under a person's question to *call* it "garbage", then yes, that's out of line. A good rule when communicating a "plain and honest" opinion is: would I say this thing if the person was sat right next to me? It is unfortunate that so many people do not apply this simple test - I think it would result in a nicer experience on the internet generally.

### Specific answer

You've asked why people stay:

- Getting good answers to their own questions
- Getting good answers to questions that have already been asked
- Learning interesting stuff from questions themselves
- Helping people by answering questions
- Helping people by pointing to guidelines, rules, and potential duplicates
- Showing people how to ask good questions
- Helping keep the site clean by getting involved in voting, editing and other aspects of community moderation
- Earning the respect of their peers
- Building a score/reputation on the site using its gamification features, in order to impress potential employers

### Background

However, I guess from some of your last posts that you have a very rough ride on Meta, earlier this year, for reasons I do not exactly follow. I edited one of your questions to remove a rather spiky email you'd sent to Stack Overflow HQ, since I thought it did not reflect well on you, and was not relevant to the question at hand. The response you received from a Stack Overflow employee was similarly spiky, and I appreciate that exchange might have put your nose out of joint a bit. As you requested, I asked a moderator to delete that post, and they have now done so.

I notice also that your profile is worried about "trolls looking for victims". We do very occasionally have trolls following people around, including outside of Stack Overflow to social media, and I agree that this phenomena is worrying in general. However, I do not know if you have experienced this to the degree that would make your worry justified, and perhaps you wrote this while still smarting from your Meta disagreement. As I indicated on your (deleted) post, I suggest you wipe the slate clean, and carry on participating on the main site, and on Meta. Whatever difficulty you have had will have been forgotten by the other participants, and it is probably best for you to do the same.

It's worth noting also that while some users can legitimately claim to have been insulted, offended, harassed or trolled, it does not follow that every disgruntled user can also make those claims. I do think Stack Overflow is a great place, and it has a lot to offer for folks looking to get answers to their programming problems, but it does require some perseverance to understand, and some positive thinking for the occasions when comments get out of line. Pop on your metaphorical Kevlar jacket, and you'll be fine.

Comment: 'A good rule when communicating a "plain and honest" opinion is: would I say this thing if the person was sat right next to me?' Yes, eventually.  If I was continually being assaulted, day after day, by work colleagues asking exactly the same question about 'i++ + ++i' undefined behaviour, I suspect that I would very soon get to the 'trash/garbage/crap' stage.

Comment: @Luciano: I am sorry to hear you are disappointed, and I'd be happy to know what sort of response you are looking for. My post above was meant to be broadly reassuring, while also not avoiding a reason why you perhaps do not see the Stack Exchange sites in a positive light. If your negative assessment of the site is purely because of the brusque tone (or occasional abuse) then yes, I agree with you.

Comment: If you are looking for solutions, then I assume the Stack Overflow team have a number of ideas they wish to try. Alternatively (and I don't mean this unkindly) maybe Stack Overflow does not fit for everyone? There are a number of smaller sites being set up that specialise in inclusionary and kind communities. I have my doubts about their viability as they grow in size, but I wish them luck notwithstanding.

Comment: @Luciano: I have made an update regarding why people may wish to stay. However, I wonder if your real question is how we can make people nicer. That is one of the hardest questions to answer, and the community has tried _a lot_ of things before - see this Meta site for many previous instances of that.

Comment: It is also hard to judge, since not every new person who perceives that an established user has been condescending or rude will be correct. I recently saw a new user telling readers that his problem was "urgent", and when I suggested that was not an appropriate way to address volunteers, he said that he needed an answer "ASAP". He got a downvote for his entitlement, and then he claimed he was "being bullied" and cited Jay's post to help me "improve my attitude". The takeaway: unfortunately, some new users just turn up with the wrong approach.

Comment: @Luciano: no, you've misunderstood. The new user was rude, entitled and sarcastic, and made a false allegation of bullying when they didn't get their precious way. If you think we need to cater to that, then my declining will disappoint you. I agree that some comments on the main site could be kinder or more welcoming, but I would advise you not to seize on Jay's post in order to justify anything you like. That approach will only harm genuine inclusion strategies, which would be counterproductive.

Comment: OK, fair enough. Nevertheless, you're trying to tackle an _enormous_ problem (building a healthy and respectful culture) without seeing all the other things we're trying to balance (quality, correctness, readability). I would urge you to participate in the main site for the long haul, and read some conversations here on Meta, to understand how much of a difficult balance this is. Best of luck.

Comment: @LucianoFCastelfranchi 'uses "urgent" instead of "ASAP" - well do we actually need any more selfish, rude posters who think that their post is more urgent than those from other users?   I thought SO was trying to avoid unnecessary and blatant rudeness?  It's nothing to do with 'funky rules', it's just everyday politeness towards volunteers who might wish to help.  Bosses and clients use 'urgent' and 'ASAP', and that's perfectly fine - they're paying, and so can set priorities.

Comment: ..and I have no problem with voting down, and voting to delete,posts from anyone who suggests that SO moderation is bullying.  It is offensive and disrespectful to those who have suffered from real bullying, cyber or otherwise.

Comment: @LucianoFCastelfranchi: I reported your remark in the last few minutes as abusive, and it insta-deleted, so you will need to post it again (minus the profanity). I don't think you are coming here with the right frame of mind. I _have_ tried to help you, and I'm just getting grumbling and aggression in reply. This will be my last response.

Comment: @Luciano: if you want to discuss privately, my email is the 'About' page of my blog, linked from my profile.

Comment: Who's been excluded?